# Angular DatePipe isn't work

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I am trying using this pipe on my angular 5 code:

```
<td class="glyphicon-center-3" >{{atividade.dt_data | date: 'dd/MM'}}</td>
```

But this isn't work for me. I can see this message in the broser console:

```
12 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'dez 9, 2018' for pipe 'DatePipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError (webpack-internal:///../../../common/esm5/common.js:4358)
at DatePipe.transform (webpack-internal:///../../../common/esm5/common.js:4540)
at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13400)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14113)
at checkAndUpdateNode (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14052)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14945)
at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14924)
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/DisciplinaPComponent.ngfactory.js:75)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14909)
at checkAndUpdateView (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14023)
```

My atividade.dt_data is of Date type. And if I don't use the pipe. The interface show me something like this "dec 9, 2018"

I get this date from my backend (Java Date). How I can show this date in this model "dd/MM"?

Comment: you have verified in debugger that atividade.dt_data is actually a javascript date and not the string value coming from your backend?

Answer (score 0):

"dec 9, 2018" is no valid Date expression. For Javascript, the format should be parsable, for example an ISO8601string, to be converted to a Date object (see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
Maybe angular's pipe supports some more variants.

So you should change your Backend to provide a parsable date string or map the field to a J's Date object on your own (e.g. with the Observale's map operator).